# How do I add a SCSIdisk that has data I want to keep?

Tags: mount

I try to mount a SCSI disk in the system, but something wrong on it.
below was my step to mount disk.

```
# mount /dev/sda /mnt/
```

[image]

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda
```

[image]

hdd list

[image]

Comment: Please replace terminal images with text.

Comment: Create a new partition by gdisk or fdisk , but I cannt see new /sda1 in the lsblk list.

Comment: You tried to mount the entire disk (`/dev/sda`) instead of the partition that contained the data, which obviously could not succeed. Then you reformatted the disk by `mkfs`, effectively destroying all data on it.

Comment: Could you please share right step how to mount SMR drive ? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, disk devices have their storage broken up into partitions which have filesystems.  Assuming sda is your scsi disk, see what partitions it has with the command (without sudo if you are running as root):

sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

The output should list one or more partitions, and their size and type.

The mount command should be issued with the -t options to specify the filesystem type, e.g. -t ext4, or -t ntfs or -t vfat  etc. of the partition selected to mount:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Another mount option that might be of interest is -o ro to mount read-only.

Unfortunately it looks like you formatted the /dev/sda, so any data on it was overwritten.  Lets hope that your scsi disk was not sda, and that sda didn't contain anything of value to you.

---

Formatting the device sda instead of a partition like sda1 wipes out the partition table in addition to any data on the disk.  Whatever you did before the mkfs was wiped.

Comment: I created a new partition for /dev/sda by gdisk or fdisk,but I cannot see the /dev/sda1 in the lsblk list.